# Using gdalwarp with a crs which doesn't have an EPSG number

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, epsg

I need to project a raster from EPSG:32642 [to this crs](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::7694).

It is a relatively new addition to the EPSG registry and the EPSG number is not yet in gdal (at least in my version: 1.11.3):

```
steph@steph-W840AU:~$ gdalsrsinfo "EPSG:7694"
ERROR 1: ERROR - failed to load SRS definition from EPSG:7694
```

I thus wanted to use gdalwarp with the WKT definition:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite 
-s_srs 'PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 42N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",69],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32642"]]' 
-t_srs 'PROJCRS["Kyrg-06 / zone 3",  
BASEGEODCRS["Kyrg-06",    DATUM["Kyrgyzstan Geodetic Datum 2006",      
ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]]],  
CONVERSION["Kyrgyzstan zone 3",    
METHOD["Transverse Mercator",ID["EPSG",9807]],    
PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252]],    
PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",74.516666666667,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252]],    
PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,SCALEUNIT["unity",1.0]],    
PARAMETER["False easting",3300000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],    
PARAMETER["False northing",14743.5,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],  
CS[cartesian,2],    
AXIS["easting (E)",east,ORDER[1]],    
AXIS["northing (N)",north,ORDER[2]],    
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0],  ID["EPSG",7694]]' 
/home/steph/Temp/python_tmp/input/rgbir.tif 
/home/steph/Temp/python_tmp/output/20160816-1117-UAVanalyse/rgbir_proj.tif
```

Which returns:

```
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
```

The WKT definition is copy-paste [from here](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::7694), so I assumed it should be working?

By the way, the definition of 32642 is not the problem: if I try to project to a well-known crs, then all works smoothly:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite 
-s_srs 'PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 42N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",69],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32642"]]' 
-t_srs 'EPSG:4326'
/home/steph/Temp/python_tmp/input/dsm.tif 
/home/steph/Temp/python_tmp/output/20160816-1127-UAVanalyse/dsm_proj.tif
```

Answer (score 5):

Well... it's actually easier than expected... So gdalwarp seems to better understand this syntax:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=74.51666666666667 +k=1 +x_0=3300000 +y_0=14743.5 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

So the full gdalwarp command is:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite 
-s_srs 'PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 42N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",69],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32642"]]' 
-t_srs '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=74.51666666666667 +k=1 +x_0=3300000 +y_0=14743.5 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs' 
/home/steph/Temp/python_tmp/input/rgbir.tif 
/home/steph/Temp/python_tmp/output/20160816-1134-UAVanalyse/rgbir_proj.tif
```

Comment: The WKT you used is a new standard (see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129764/how-are-esri-wkt-projections-different-from-ogc-wkt-projections), which is not yet implemented in GDAL (https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2016-April/044067.html). Your workaround is correct, but missing a datum shift. The EPSG registry does not mention any datum shift to WGS84, so I assume it can be set to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Where / how should I add this datum shift?

Comment: It gets added with `+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0`. If you transform from DHDN or any Pulkovo datum to WGS-based CRS, it is mandatory on both sides, even if it is all zero for one side. EPSG codes inside GDAL mostly have it by default.