# writeOGR() not writing out datum of shp

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I am writing out a shp, in ESRI shapefile driver. In R, the projection of this shp is

```
+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0
+y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

I wrote this shp out as below-

```
writeOGR(x_projected, dsn="address path","name of shp to be stored", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

However, on reading this projected, written shp back in, I see that the datum specified by +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 does not exist. Also, when plotting this shp in ArcMap or QGIS, the datum is known confirming that the datum has not been written out.

Why is writeOGR() not writing out the datum i.e. why is the +towgd84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 component missing?

Comment: If it were written, with all zero parameters it would have no effect at all. Would you like to test a principle or do you have some practical problem?

Comment: See this @user30184 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291734/usa-albers-equal-area-conic-usgs-version-landfire-projection-not-read-by-r-or/291749#291749

Comment: There's a bunch of datums that could match +towgd84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 and GRS80 and the US extent of the parameters: NAD83, NAD83 HARN, 2011, NSRS2007. If you don't look at the parameters, SIRGAS, NAD83 CSRS, etc.

Comment: @user30184 even with a `+towgs84` parameter that *isnt* all zeroes I don't get it written to the shapefile .prj file. I'm wondering if its not part of the shapefile prj format...

Comment: @mkennedy wrote a few years ago in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129764/how-are-esri-wkt-projections-different-from-ogc-wkt-projections `We don't support TOWGS84 nor some of the newer keywords.` And that GDAL does not write it into .prj can be verified with command `gdalsrsinfo -o wkt_esri "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=1,1,1,1,1,1,1 +units=m +no_defs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [following wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PROJ.4):

> **Datum**
>
> You can use the +nadgrids-Parameter to select an existing
>   gridfile or define your own datum with the +towgs84 Parameter to use a
>   3- or 7-Parameter Transformation. To use the buildin "datums" (or
>   dati?) you can use the +datum-Parameter and select one of the
>   DatumCode in the following list from pj_datums.c (e.g. +datum=NAD27).

Is weird, defining `+towgs84=` in R, as:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
meuse_nad83 <- spTransform(meuse, "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ")         
writeOGR(meuse_nad83, dsn="/path/to","name", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

You got this from QGIS:

[image]

But, if you define `+datum=`:

```
meuse_nad83b <- spTransform(meuse, "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs ")         
writeOGR(meuse_nad83b, dsn="/to/path","name", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

You got:

[image]

I can't answer why `writeOGR()` doesn't work, just recommend you to use `+datum=` parameter

Comment: Thanks @aldo_tapia, above worked i.e. adding +datum=NAD83. However, wondering if this will work for rasters and when using writeRaster(). I have to project a couple of rasters to this USGS albers equal area conic projection too and want to know if it will work. Do you know?

Comment: @tg110 probably. This issue is writing vectors with OGR, rasters are written with GDAL

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `rgdal` doesn't write the `toWGS84` parameter to shapefiles:

If I create two identical objects in R, but with slightly different `+towgs84` parameters:

```
> proj4string(d1)
[1] "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=1,0,1,0,1,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
> proj4string(d0)
[1] "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
```

then write to Shapefile, the `.prj` files are identical and show no trace of a datum shift parameter. `ogrinfo` tells me:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
```

for both files.

However, if I write them to a Geopackage,

```
> writeOGR(d0,"./d0.gpkg","d0","GPKG",overwrite=TRUE)
> writeOGR(d1,"./d1.gpkg","d1","GPKG",overwrite=TRUE)
```

I get the parameter stored and `ogrinfo` shows it:

For `d0`:

```
GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
```

and for `d1`:

```
GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101],
        TOWGS84[1,0,1,0,1,0,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
```

I'm not sure why this happens - I first thought that `+toWGS84` datum shifts weren't supported in ESRI PRJ file format, but I have some shapefiles with `TOWGS84` in them that seem to work fine:

```
DATUM["North_American_Datum_1927",
    SPHEROID["Clarke_1866",6378206.4,294.9786982138982,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7008"]],
    TOWGS84[-9.0,151.0,185.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6267"]],
```

But in any event, I'd recommend you use Geopackages from now on.

Comment: Mkennedy wrote also here https://community.esri.com/thread/72905 that ESRI does not support towgs84. It would be nice to know if that it still true. But the problem disappers with OGC WKT v.2 http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/12-063r5/12-063r5.html because the whole towgs84 is removed.

Answer (score 0):

My *ad hoc* fix is to replace the resulting *.prj file for one I know works (*.prj files are accompanying text files with the CRS definition). For example, when I save a *.shp file in SWEREF99TM (EPSG:3006) in QGIS the resulting *.prj file contains:

```
PROJCS["SWEREF99_TM",GEOGCS["GCS_SWEREF99",DATUM["D_SWEREF99",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",15.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Then, when I save a spatial object in R using rgdal::writeOGR() I replace the resulting  *.prj file/s with the one I know works. I even did a little function to replace all *.prj file in a folder.

```
fixPrj <- function(dir, sourceDir = td, CRS){ 
   ## update with all available options from epsg.choices in global
   sourceFile <- switch(CRS, "+init=epsg:3006" = "SWEREF99TM.prj",
                        "+init=epsg:4326" = "WGS84.prj",
                        "+init=epsg:3857" = "WGS84PM.prj")

   prjFiles <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = ".prj")  
   prjNames <- unlist(strsplit(prjFiles, split = ".prj"))  
   file.copy(from = paste0(sourceDir, "/", sourceFile),  
          to = paste0(dir,"/", prjNames,".prj"),   
          overwrite = TRUE)  
}
```