Explanation of syntax and parameters of a sample UTM projection file
I am interested to have explanation of syntax and parameters of a sample UTM projection file, reproduced below;
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_43N_Karam@5.5",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",298257.5757575759],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",75.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["",1.676403352806705]]

Put on a pot of coffee and read about WKT Parameters

@Pointdump, the "WKT Parameters" document doesn't epxlains the "@5.5" string.

@Andrea Giudiceandrea, The Karam is a unit of length, like feet and meters. I think it's equal to 5.5 feet.

Is a Karam 1.676403352806705 metres perchance? The "Karam@5.5" in the <crs name> parameter of the PROJCS element has no function except as a label. The units used by the projection are defined in the UNIT element, in metres...

This is a projected coordinate system with this name:
PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_43N_Karam@5.5",

which is based on a geographic (Earth-based) coordinate system with this name:
  GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",

which uses this model for the earth:
   DATUM["D_WGS_1984",

which is a spheroid of this radius in metres and a flattening of 1/298.2:
     SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]
     ],

all based on the Greenwich meridian at 0 longitude:
   PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],

and all measured in degrees:
   UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
  ],

with the shape of the earth decided, we're going to do a Mercator projection but Transverse, so like a world map projection but with the equator running N-S:
  PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],

Our zero X coordinates have this added to them
  PARAMETER["False_Easting",298257.5757575759],

And this added to our Y coordinates:
  PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],

And our Mercator projection is going to be centred on this longitude:
  PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",75.0],

And we're going to scale everything by this factor. I don't know why:
  PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],

With our 0 coordinate at 0 latitude.
  PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],

and one unit of X or Y is going to be 1.676403 metres, which I hear is a "Karam":
  UNIT["",1.676403352806705]
]


I would mention that the datum name "D_WGS_1984" means the same as "WGS_1984" . The D_ part is something that ESRI tends to add https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/129993/30184

@Spacedman, Scale Factor balances out the scale distortion each side of the central meridian. All UTM's use that same 0.9996.

The false easting, which is normally 500000 meters, was probably adjusted automatically when the unit was changed to use a karam or the definer changed it as false easting/northing parameters use the same unit as the projcs itself.
